# JQgrid show message before update and multiple update

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am working on JQgrid and trying to achieve some specific functionality. These functionalists are 
1)inline update with message shown before update.
2)Multiple update

I tried to read jqgrid and got this code https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/byygepy3/11/ . Which is quite approximate to my requirement but it doesn't contain multiple update and message shown before update.

I tried to overwrite these code but maximum i reached is this https://jsfiddle.net/byygepy3/72/  but failed because multiple update only updating half of record and it doesn't show any message before updating either single row or multiple row.

code is inserting just allow me to ask question.

```
$(function () {
    var myData = [
            { id: 10, ParameterName: "Test", ParameterValue: "" },
            { id: 20, ParameterName: "Test 1", ParameterValue: "" },
            { id: 30, ParameterName: "Test 2", ParameterValue: "" },
            { id: 40, ParameterName: "Test 2", ParameterValue: "" },
            { id: 50, ParameterName: "Test 2", ParameterValue: "" },
            { id: 60, ParameterName: "Test 2", ParameterValue: "" }
        ],
        $grid = $("#list");

    // change the text displayed on editrules: {required: true } 
    $.extend(true, $.jgrid.locales["en-US"].edit.msg, {
        required: "No value was entered for this parameter!!!"
    });

    $grid.jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        data: myData,
        colNames: ["", "Parameter Name", "Parameter Value"],
        colModel: [
            { name: "act", template: "actions" }, // optional feature
            { name: "ParameterName" },
            { name: "ParameterValue", editable: true,
                editoptions: { maxlength: 100 }, editrules: {required: true } }
        ],
        cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true },
        autoResizing: { compact: true },
        pager: true,
        pgbuttons: false,     // disable page control like next, back button
        pgtext: null,         // disable pager text like 'Page 0 of 10'
        viewrecords: true,    // disable current view record text like 'View 1-10 of 100'
        sortname: "Name",
        iconSet: "fontAwesome",
        caption: 'Parameters',
        autowidth: true,
        hidegrid: false,
        inlineEditing: {
            keys: true
        },
        singleSelectClickMode: "selectonly", // prevent unselect once selected rows
        beforeSelectRow: function (rowid) {
             // allow selection if saving successful
        },
        onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
            $(this).jqGrid("editRow", rowid);
        },
        afterSetRow: function (options) {
            var item = $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", options.rowid);
            if (item != null) {
                item.dirty = true;
            }
        },
        navOptions: {
            edit: false,
            add: false,
            search: false,
            deltext: "Delete",
            refreshtext: "Refresh"
        },
        inlineNavOptions: {
            save: false,
            savetext: "Save",
            cancel: false,
            restoreAfterSelect: false
        },
        formDeleting: {
            // delete options
            url: window.g_baseUrl + 'MfgTransactions_MVC/COA/Delete?',
            beforeSubmit: function () {
                // get value
                var selRowId = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                var parametricValue = $(this).jqGrid('getCell', selRowId, 'ParameterValue');

                // check if empty
                if (parametricValue === "") {
                    return [false, "Cannot delete: No value exists for this parameter"];
                }

                return [true, "Successfully deleted"];
            },
            delData: {
                batchId: function () {
                    return $("#BatchId").val();
                }
            },
            closeOnEscape: true,
            closeAfterDelete: true,
            width: 400,
            msg: "Are you sure you want to delete the Parameter?",
            afterComplete: function (response) {
                if (response.responseText) {
                    alert("response.responseText");
                }

                //loadBatchListIntoGrid();
            }
        }
    }).jqGrid('navGrid')
    .jqGrid('inlineNav')
    .jqGrid('navButtonAdd', {
        caption: "Save Changed",
        buttonicon: "fa-floppy-o",
        onClickButton: function () {
            var $self = $(this), i,
                // savedRows array is not empty if some row is in inline editing mode
                savedRows = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow");
            for (i = 0; i < savedRows.length; i++) {
                    $self.jqGrid("saveRow", savedRows[i].id);    
            }

            var localData = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "data"),
                dirtyData = $.grep(localData, function (item) {
                    return item.dirty;
                });
            alert(dirtyData.length > 0 ? JSON.stringify(dirtyData) : "no dirty data");
        }
    });

    // make more place for navigator buttons be rwducing the width of the right part
    var pagerIdSelector = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "pager");
    $(pagerIdSelector + "_right").width(100);

    // make the grid responsive
    $(window).bind("resize", function () {
        $grid.jqGrid("setGridWidth", $grid.closest(".container-fluid").width());
    }).triggerHandler("resize");
});
```

Comment: It's not full clear what you want to implement. You use both `template: "actions"` (`formatter: "actions"`) and calls `editRow` inside of `onSelectRow`. Which way should use the user? Additionally you call `editRow` without calling `saveRow` on selection of another row (holding other changed **unsaved**). On the other side you want "1)inline update with message shown before update". Do you want to display messages only on clicking "Save Changed" button? In general "Save Changed" looks good. You wrote about "2)Multiple update". What is not working currently?

Comment: the code was written by someone other.....i found it and tried to manipulate it according to my needs, which i failed.....what i basically wants is 1)  before saving or updating anything either single or multiple row together  a confirmation dialog box should appear and 2) multiple update on single click ( save changes button) i.e if user edit many rows and want to save altogether (which is currently not working and it saves only alternate rows).

Answer (score 0):

Free jqGrid supports a lot of callbacks, which will be used during saving the rows. You can use for example `beforeSaveRow` callback of inline editing, custom validation via `editrules.custom` callback function, `beforeSelectRow` and other. Additionally, your code seems to distinguish the initial empty value `""` of `ParameterValue` column from any other values. The final code you should made yourself. I posted an example

```js
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid) {
    // allow selection if saving successful
    var $self = $(this), i,
        savedRows = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow");

    for (i = 0; i < savedRows.length; i++) {
        if (rowid !== savedRows[i].id) {
            if (allowSaving.call(this, savedRows[i].id)) {
                $self.jqGrid("saveRow", savedRows[i].id);
            } else {
                $self.jqGrid("restoreRow", savedRows[i].id);
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
},
```

with `allowSaving` function defined as

```
var allowSaving = function (rowid) {
        var item = $(this).jqGrid("getRowData", rowid);
        if (item.ParameterValue !== "") {
            return confirm("Do you want to save \"" +
                        item.ParameterValue  + "\" value in \"" +
                        item.ParameterName + "\"?");
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };
```

It allows to ask the user to confirm the changes of `ParameterName`. Additionally the code of "Save Changed" button should be adjusted too.

See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/byygepy3/74/